# What is the best way of building repeating layouts in a grid?

Tags: android, xml

I need to repeat the same layout (card) in a grid layout, the cards will have to look the same, but the content (text) inside has to change for each card.

What is the best way to instantiate those cards?

Can this be done with xml fragments?

I ***prefer defining the card layout in xml*** to have more control over it's design.

***EDIT:***
The cards should be placed in a specific row and column inside the layout, some cells will be empty and some will have a card in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i prefer, use java code to define the layout params instead of xml. 
It will better control your logic. 
Try to make a method that define single card params and add it into your main grid view.
You can also use view group for this case.